# Map with darker water

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-styling

Can you post a link to a gmap that has darker water, then I could look which value to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Dark Water Style Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     var darkStyle = [{
       featureType: 'water',
       elementType: 'all',
       stylers: [{ invert_lightness: true }, { hue: '#3300ff' }]
     }];

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       mapTypeControlOptions: {
         mapTypeIds: ['darkwater', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
       },
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0),
       zoom: 1,
       mapTypeId: 'darkwater'
     });

     map.mapTypes.set('darkwater', new google.maps.StyledMapType(darkStyle, { name: 'Dark' }));
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Is this dark enough?

[image: Google Maps Dark Water Style Demo]

This is using the new [Styled Map features](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps) of the [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). You may also want to check out the [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) which will allow you to graphically edit styles.

Comment: Close to perfect leaving me wish more like black than the blue and the landscape from the Terrain map. Thank you Dear Sir!

Comment: @LarsOn: Try using the Style Map Wizard: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html. Click on water, and change the hue and other settings. Then click on "View JSON" and simply replace the JSON object with the one used in `darkStyle` in my example.

Comment: Thanks! You may inspect the choice 'Dark' I deployed to http://www.koolbusiness.com/